# I want to make multiple blocks be placed in a /fill command in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I dont know how to have multiple blocks placed in one fill command, without doing /summon Fallingsand {} and so on. I guess I could just look at a command that does it.

Comment: Do you mean different types of blocks (e.g: stone, sand, dirt all in one command), or just multiple blocks (e.g: place 16 blocks at once)?

Comment: different types, the same block is easy

Comment: Not possible with a single `/fill` command then, AFAIK.

Comment: After the edit your question stopped making sense to me... What do you mean by "stained glass doesn't work"? What does the quote about fear mean? O_O

Comment: Do you want to summon blocks with block data, like colored stained glass?

Comment: Please don't ask a completely different question in the same question.  If you have other questions, you can always ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Fill commands only has one parameter to specify what to fill with:

```
fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <TileName> [dataValue] [oldBlockHandling] [dataTag]
```

where `<TileName> [dataValue] ... [dataTag]` define the block. You can specify block's data value and NBT parameters to choose block subtype (slab material, orientation, glass color, etc.), but it is impossible to fill one volume with two different blocks. *(How would the game decide between them for each block in the volume, anyway?)*

Comment: I'll do it how IJAMinecraft does it so I don't run into issues

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do it with `/fill` but you can do it by using this:

```
/summon FallingSand {Block:iron_block,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Block:redstone_block,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Block:activator_rail,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:FallingSand,Block:MinecartCommandBlock,Command:{setblock ~2 ~ ~ dirt}}]}]}]}
```

Or look at [this](https://ijaminecraft.com/cmd/difficulty_horror_1.10/) if you want something more professional.

Please keep in mind that I am typing this off of memory, don't tell me off if anything is wrong, just say what is wrong in the comments, and I will fix it.

Comment: Good to hear you have solved your problem. But anyone who stumbles on this question later won't have a clue about what you did. Can you please write a more comprehensive answer, so it could be helpful to other people later? (You can also accept your own answer as correct, no shame in that)

Comment: I'll delete or in any way I can fix it

Comment: I hope it will help

Comment: Answered my own question lol

Answer (score 0):

Do /fill then both of your coordinates, 50 wood, 50 stone or any other block. It will be random but both of the blocks will be placed.

Comment: This answer is a bit confusing. Could you reword it?